# How to run multiple instances of an executable using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have been trying to find a better way to run multiple instances of an EXE written in C#.NET.

I already have a working code but its lagging the app needs improvements.
Here is what I have so far.

```
public void startProcess(int Threads)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(200, 800)); 
            for (int i = 1; i <= Threads; i++)
            {                  
                //Proxy Settings Goes There.......
                Client.find_super_proxy();
                string proxy = Client.super_proxy_ip;
                if (proxy.Length <= 8)
                {
                    Client clnt = new Client();
                    clnt.logout();
                    clnt.login();
                    Client.find_super_proxy();
                    proxy = Client.super_proxy_ip;
                }

                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Browse.exe"))
                {
                    Arguments = string.Concat(new object[] { proxy.ToString(), " ", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtURL.Text), " ", this.nuInner.Value, " ", random.Next((int)this.nuDelay.Value, (int)this.nuDelay1.Value), " ", this.nuTimeOut.Value, " ", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userAgent), " ", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(referrer) })
                };
                Process process2 = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = info,
                    EnableRaisingEvents = true
                };
                process2.Start();
            }

        }
```

And Then I am calling this method like this in timer.

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        runningthreads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Browse").Length;

        if ( runningthreads < (int)nuThreads.Value )
        {
            int newThread =  (int)nuThreads.Value - runningthreads;
            Random random = new Random();
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(200, 800));
            startProcess(newThread);

        }

    }
```

This code is making a big mess hanging the whole program I have been thinking to use it in BackgroundWorker with some improvements.

Comment: Instead of `Thread.Sleep()` increase the timer interval.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Tried it mate but not worth anything.

Comment: Note that you have `Thread.Sleep()` two times: in `timer2_Tick()` and in `startProcess()`. Remove them all. That's what's blocking your UI thread

Comment: @ThomasWeller That was somehow important for my thing, like what I wanted to start the other instance after a little random delay.

Comment: Ah, I understand: you want a slow app, but still responsive. Perhaps that makes sense. Not for me though. Good luck. Try starting the processes in a new thread, but be told that you run into other issues, i.e. Process.GetByName() will not consider unstarted processes.